# How do I export a JDeveloper project to a zip file?

Tags: jdeveloper

I work with eclipse for decades. If I want to export a project to a zip file and open it into another eclipse, it's trivial.

But I am really feeling stupid because I don't know how to do the same with JDeveloper.

Is there any menu command or button that I can just click and export my JDeveloper project to hand to some other developer?

Answer (score 0):

Not from inside JDeveloper - but you can just zip the directory where your project is from outside the IDE and pass is over to the other user.

Comment: and then it's just a matter of closing and opening the IDE to detect the new project?